# Can't run maven-versions-plugin:set when the parent-child relationship is one-directional and not bi-directional

Tags: maven, maven-reactor, maven-versions-plugin

In Maven, you can have one parent pom / Reactor which references child modules through the use of the parent's `modules` section like this:

```
<modules>
    <module>simple-weather</module>
    <module>simple-webapp</module>
</modules>
```

However, each child is free to specify **or NOT** its parent, and it still gets built; that means, the following piece of config is optional in for `simple-weather` and `simple-webapp` `pom.xml` s:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multi</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
```

When using `maven-versions-plugin`, and attempting to update the version of all child modules, I've found that if you're NOT specifying the `parent` in your child pom.xml (or if the child references a different parent), then version updates no longer propagate to the children.

Do you know why is that, and/or how I can workaround this?
I should mention that I really do need to have my children `pom.xml`s with different parents, so it is not really an option to put the Reactor's pom.xml as their parent (for example one module is a client module which inherits from company's standard `pom.xml` for client modules, while the other is a server module which inherits from company's standard `pom.xml` for server modules).

Comment: We have the same problem with different parent poms. We are planning to move all company parent poms into one, and activate/deactivate the different project types with profiles.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how that would work. You'd still make your child projects to have a different parent than the reactor (albeit all siblings will now share the same parent).

Comment: No, the parent inherits from the company pom, and the child projects activate the necessary profiles.